# Can't find element in DOM after loading it with ajax (want to bind jquery plug in to it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

So I have 2 html pages. 1 that functions as container and 1 that functions as content.
When I load the content page with a table I'm able to use drag and drop.

But when I go to my container page and load the content page into a div with ajax, the drag and drop stops working. All other javascript functionalities inside the content page still work. How can I bind the jquery dnd plugin to the table loaded with ajax?

I'm using drag & drop with this as tutorial http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

my code looks like this:

```
$(window).load(function()
{   if(temp == 0)
    { 
        DP("eerste keer")
        load_table(); 
        temp = 1;
    }
} );

function load_table()
{    
    DP('load_table');
    $.ajax({
            //async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/diagnose_hoofdpagina/table_diagnose/" + DosierID, // <== loads requested page
            success: function (data) {
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").html(''); //<== clears current content of div
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").append(data).trigger('create'); // <== appends requested page
                },
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
              } 
        }).done(function() {
        update_table(); 
        initialize_table();    // <== calls jquery plug in
        });

    return false;   
}


function initialize_table() 
{
    var tableid = $('#diagnoses_zelf table').attr('id'); //< this finds the correct table thanks to Fábio Batista => this option worked, rest didn't
    alert(tableid);
    $(tableid).tableDnD({    
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
        alert(table + "     "  +  row);

        },
        onDragStart: function(table,row){
        var tette = $(row).index;
        alert(tette);
        },
        dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
    });     
}
```

[image]

How is this possible and what can I do about it?
Can anyone help me with this please.

Very short:
I want access to the ID of the table I load into my container page with ajax and use the jquery drag and drop plug in on it.

**EDIT**

*Findings:*

Somehow my table in the container page got renamed to **pSqlaTable** instead of the id I gave to it in the controller page which is.

```
<table id="tableDiagnose" class="table table-hover">
```

Thats why the code couldn't find the table annymore Got fixed by this code thanks to Fábio Batista:

```
$('#diagnoses_zelf table').tableDnD( ... );
```

, but how can I use the dnd plugin now ?

**It finds the table now, but I'm still not able to bind the dnd plugin to it, Am I able to bind a jquery plug in to ajax loaded tables ?**

**EDIT**

```
//drag & drop http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/
function initialize_table() 
{
    var tableid = $('#diagnoses_zelf table').attr('id');
    alert(tableid);
    $('#' + tableid).tableDnD({    
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
        alert(table + "     "  +  row);

        },
        onDragStart: function(table,row){
        alert('issemer?');
        },
        dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
    });    
}
```

This is the code i'm still stuck with. tableid is correct but the initialisation of the jquery isn't. I can't drag the drows in the table. Is my syntax wrong ?

**EDIT**

**Could it be that I can't bind the jquery to the table because I dynamicaly generate the table on the other page with ZPT (or javascript) ?**

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck here" on the .tableDnD line? Is any error printed to the JS console? If so please include it. If not, you're probably right that it can't find the #tableDiagnose element, and I'd check to make sure the HTML is being created with that ID correctly.

Comment: There are no errors given, I will check if the table gets the right id, but that shouldn't be the problem.
Just in case. Is it not possible to just include the working controller into the container page at all? Or do I really need to put my logic of dnd on the container page?

Comment: It IS possible to embed HTML (e.g. your controller) into a container without breaking JS events, but this involves either using special JS methods (like .detach and .append) *after* the HTML is initialized front-end, or else making sure your IDs don't change, per your solution below. Which, I think, would be a separate back-end bug you're seeing. ...As far as putting the "logic of dnd on the container page" I would consider modularizing that JS into a shared .js file that can be re-used as needed, if you need it in multiple places.

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` and show us that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The issue with plugins.

You're mixing lots of external libraries and code. This results in possible mis-matches between versions, and a lot of black boxes in your code.

As a developer, this should make you feel very uneasy. Having code you do not fully understand in your code base can get really frustrating really fast.

#### The alternative.

Often, these sort of plugins provide functionality we, as JavaScript developers can accomplish just as easily without them. This development process, in simple enough scenarios, lets us create code we understand and have an easier time maintaining. Not only do we learn from this process, but we also create smaller bits of specific code. Community driven solutions are very good in general, but it's important to remember they're not a silver bullet. Often you're stuck using a not-so-active project which has a bug for your specific case and you have to dig through a large, unfamiliar code base.

### Your code

So what does this drag and drop plugin do?

Well, I'd break it down as the following:

- Listens to [the `mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mousedown) event on table rows
- When such an event fires, start moving the table row to match the mouse position
- When [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/mouseup?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseup) occurs, detect that, and finalize the position.

Let us see how we can do something similar. 
Let's assume the table's HTML is something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Hello 1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td> Hello 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is a fiddle with the table with some basic styling applied](http://jsfiddle.net/YCWxF/)

Next, we'll listen to the selection events. We'll add an event to the table rows for selection and to the document to when the mouse is up. jQuery has event listeners for such events. Since we want these events to stick even after AJAX, we'll use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which lets us use delegated events. `.on` means that even if we add content to the table later, it won't matter.

```
var selected; // currently selected row
$(document).on("mousedown","#MySpecialTable tr",function(){
   $("#textDiv").text(this.textContent); 
    selected = this;
});
$(document).on("mouseup",function(){
    $("#textDiv").text("Left "+selected.textContent); 
    selected = null;
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9yyE/) of such code.

Now, we'll want to actually change the drag&drop to work when, that is, update the current position to the one reflecting the mouse position. We can listen to `mousemove` events, and detect the element we're currently on. Something like

```
$(document).on("mousemove",function(e){
    $("#textDiv").text($(e.target).html());
});
```

[You can see a working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/YJh2t/)

That's nice, but we want to actually change the element position. So we'll need to change the table structure to allow that. We can remove the element, and append it at the correct position. We'll check if we have a selected element, and if we do, we can track it compared to the current element in the mousemove event. We can for starters detect if we should drag with something like:

```
$(document).on("mousemove",function(e){
    if(selected !=null){// got an element selected
        if($("#MySpecialTable").has(e.target).length > 0){ //in the table
            $("#mousePos").text("DRAGGING");    
        }
    }else{
        $("#mousePos").text("NOT SELECTED");
    }
});
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/96hWU/)

Now, we'll add actual selection, we'll replace the elements when the target is not our element and we're in the table. Our full code should be something like:

```
var selected;
$(document).on("mousedown","#MySpecialTable tr",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//stop the text selection;
   $("#textDiv").text(this.textContent); 
    selected = $(this);
    selected.find("td").css("background-color","#999");
});
$(document).on("mouseup",function(){
    $("#textDiv").text("Left "+selected.text()); 
    selected.find("td").css("background-color","");
    selected = null;
});
$(document).on("mousemove",function(e){
    if(selected !=null){// got an element selected
        if($("#MySpecialTable").has(e.target).length > 0){ //in the table
            var el = $(e.target).closest("tr");//the tr element we're on
            el.before(selected);// replace the elements
        }
    }else{
        $("#mousePos").text("NOT SELECTED");
    }
});

$("#MySpecialTable").on('selectstart', false);//Don't let the user select the table
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emYdV/))

Now, so far we only have a few lines of code, which is nice since we know exactly what's going on and didn't need to use lots of lines of external code we don't fully understand.

But will it AJAX?

Let's load the data into the table with AJAX and see! We'll simulate an AJAX response using a `setTimeout` which would allow us to simulate an asynchronous request. We'll use

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#MySpecialTable").html("<tr><td> Hello 1</td></tr><tr><td> Hello 2</td></tr><tr><td> Hello 3</td></tr><tr><td> Hello 4</td></tr><tr><td> Hello 5</td></tr><tr><td> Hello 6</td></tr>");
},1000);
```

This means, update the HTML of `#MySpecialTable` after one second. Let's see if it works shall we?

[So why does it work?](http://jsfiddle.net/PGmNH/) well, we used [delegated events](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) which means we don't care if the elements we're loading are in the screen right now or not. We had the insight to do this since we built our code ourselves and knew what our final goal was. The only thing left to do is clean the code a little.

We'll wrap our code in the following, to prevent $ from being an issue in non-conflict mode (that is, $ is already taken in the page:

```
(function($){

})(jQuery);
```

Next we'll add a binding for our table event:

```
$.GertVDragTable = function(elementSelector){ // rest of code.
```

Eventually, our code might [look something like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/25nvk/)

Using it, would be a simple `$.GertVDragTable("#MySpecialTable");` alternatively, we can put it on `$.fn` and allow every function to call it. Which is a matter of taste.

No copy-pasta please :) I'd appreciate it if you stop on every stage and think *why* the next step was taken.

Comment: Not the answer to how to implement the jquery. 
But helped me do the trick of starting my own dnd. Thanks for the help and the good post.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the ID as a selector, you can use any expression that can find your table.

If there's only one table on the resulting `$.ajax` call, you can search for "a table inside the container", using the container ID, which won't change:

```
$('#diagnoses_zelf table').tableDnD( ... );
```

If there's more than one table, use a different kind of selector, instead of the ID. A CSS class works fine:

```
$('table.table-diagnose').tableDnD( ... );
```

So does a `data-` attribute:

```
$("table[data-diagnose]").tableDnD( ... );
```

Comment: Keep in mind `data` attribute is HTML5 attribute and isn't supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `title` to your table, like so:

```
<table id = "tableDiagnose" class = "table table-hover" title = "table-content">
```

Then use the jQuery [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find this table instead of finding it by `id`.

```
$('table[title="table-content"]').tableDnD({ 
// the rest of your code
```

Comment: It's a nice piece of code, but the suggestion of Fábio Batista workerd fine  for me. `$('#diagnoses_zelf table').tableDnD( ... );`

Comment: it helped me a little, It didn't fix the problem so i'm not going to accept it as an answer. sry.

Answer (score 1):

If your id is changing you should not use an ID then:

```
<table class="tableDiagnose table table-hover">
```

**Plugin**

```
function initialize_table() 
{
    $('.tableDiagnose.table').tableDnD({    
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
        alert(table + "     "  +  row);
        },
        dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
    });   
    DP('nee');  
}
```

**EDIT**: ajax is asynchronous :

```
function load_table()
{    
    DP('load_table');
    $.ajax({
            //async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/diagnose_hoofdpagina/table_diagnose/" + DosierID, // <== loads requested page
            success: function (data) {
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").html(''); //<== clears current content of div
                    $("#diagnoses_zelf").append(data).trigger('create'); // <== appends requested page
                    update_table(); 
                    initialize_table();    // <== calls jquery plug in
                },
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
              } 
        });
        //removed .done as you already have a success option in ajax


    return false;   
}
```

EDIT: found your bug........
you retrieve the table id then select it in $(tableid) but you missed the `#`

```
function initialize_table() 
{
    /*
    var tableid = $('#diagnoses_zelf table').attr('id'); //< this finds the correct table thanks to Fábio Batista => this option worked, rest didn't
    alert(tableid);
    // but you really should limit the use of variables when you don't need them*/
    //$('#'+tableid).tableDnD({            
    //like this directly
    $('#diagnoses_zelf table').tableDnD({    
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
        alert(table + "     "  +  row);

        },
        onDragStart: function(table,row){
        var tette = $(row).index;
        //alert(tette);
        },
        dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
    });     
}
```

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/8qTUT/)

**EDIT**

Comment: thanks for your input, I used `$('#diagnoses_zelf table').tableDnD( ... );` to fix the (can't find my table id problem)

Comment: I've looked a bit into the code, try `$.tableDnD.makeDraggable($('#diagnoses_zelf table'))`

Comment: where should I put this because I can't see how this would help me bind the plugin to the table.

Comment: @GertV ah sry I got it wrong. It's because you init the table before the ajax has done its work. make the ajax synchronous with option `async:false` or move the init code inside the `success` (prefered solution`. see my edited answer

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but It doesn't work. I've already tried that. I added the .done because it wouldn't initialize the table when I put initialize_table() in the succes.Both when the ajax request was assynchronous and not.

Comment: then it's weird... maybe you have an error inside the `success` handler. I think removing it from `success` would hide the true error. Or move everything inside `.done`

Comment: The only thing that's in my succes is adding the table to my page. I thought that if I waited for the ajax call to be done to initialize the table it wouldn't give me this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30829/discussion-between-gertv-and-techunter)

Comment: The only thing that's in my succes is adding the table to my page. I thought that if I waited for the ajax call to be done to initialize the table it wouldn't give me this problem.
From what I have now I can tell the plugin can find my table because it updates my mouse pointer to a "dragable icon" + the table is initialized in the DOM because I can find the table ID. I guess I just can't get the rows draggable at this moment.

Comment: @GertV got it working. but again please use `success:function(){}` OR `.done(function(){})` but not both or it gets messy

Comment: What do you mean u got it working ? I placed all of it in succes now.

Comment: @GertV see my edit section. you forgot the `#` in the table id selector

Comment: I don't know how that works in your fiddle, I'm using exact the same code. I was first using `$('#tableDiagnose').tableDnD` so that alone can't be it :/

Comment: I'll let you know my findings, I'm gonnafully review my code again now since it does work in your example.

Comment: @GertV I've deleted the `update_table()` because you didn't provide it. Any console error? (F12 to get the console)

Comment: Doesn't give anny error, I realy don't know why it isn't working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the script file in the container page or in the content page? I guess you might want to try to load it when calling the dnd plugin with getScript:

```
...
$.getScript('pathTotableDnDlib').done(function(){
    $(tableid).tableDnD({    
    onDrop: function(table, row) {
    alert(table + "     "  +  row);

    },
    onDragStart: function(table,row){
    var tette = $(row).index;
    alert(tette);
    },
    dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
});});
...
```

more on getscript: [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: Firstly I added it into my content page. Everything worked there untill I loaded it into my container page. I transfered the code to my container page now. The script itself is callable, thats why I don't understand why I can't bind it to the table. Am I able to bind a jquery plug in to loaded content ?

Comment: @GertV sure you can. if the id is correct, the content is loaded fine, and the plugin itself is loaded and...'plugable'. you may want to try to load the content and try to bind the plugin from developers console. to check if the plugin is loaded, just try to call $().tableDnD, it should input the function string, if it does, try to call the initialize_table(), if the plugin (after the call) is bounded, then it may be a problem of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

@BenjaminGruenbaum Hi thx a lot  for the tutorial, i modified a bit the code to block the drag n'drop on table headers and to improve the drag fluidity tracking the mouse direction.

```
var old_y = 0;
(function ($) {
    $.GertVDragTable = function (tableName) {
        var selected;
        $(document).on("mousedown", tableName+" tr",function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //stop the text selection;
            if (($(this).find('th').length)== 0){   //prevent dragging on tr containing th
            selected = $(this);
            selected.find("td").css("background-color", "black");
            selected.find("td").css("color", "white");
            }
        });

        $(document).on("mouseup", function () {
            selected.find("td").css("background-color", "");
            selected.find("td").css("color", "");
            selected = null;
        });
        $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
            if (selected != null ) { // got an element selected
                if ($(tableName).has(e.target).length > 0) { //in the table
                    var el = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //the tr element we're on
                    if (el.find('th').length==0){ //prevent dropping on headers row

                    if (e.pageY > old_y){       //**
                    el.after(selected);}else{   //**-->more fluid dragging based on mouse direction
                        el.before(selected);    //**
                    }

                }
                }
                old_y = e.pageY;
            }
        });

        $(tableName).on('selectstart', false); //Don't let the user select the table
    }
})(jQuery);
```

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/59rdq/

I hope it will be useful for someone.