# jquery-jtable - how can i tell which column is sorted?

Tags: php, jquery-jtable

using JQuery-JTable, I'm adding support for drag and drop to reorder.

Got drag and drop working based on this answer [jQuery JTable how to drag rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336003/jquery-jtable-how-to-drag-rows)

Now I'm concerned that reorder only makes sense if the table is already sorted by the order column.  If its sorted by another column, I'm not really sure what the user wants to do.

Was thinking of making the drag/drop support only enabled when the table is sorted by the order column and when sorted on other columns, disable that aspect.

Is there an event that fires when the sort column changes?

Comment: you want the user can sort some collumns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The source :](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/SelectingRows)
if you want disable sort on one collumn :

```
RecordDate: {
                title: 'Record date',
                width: '15%',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                sorting: false  // here , you can specify that it's not sortable
            }
```

if you want disable it on the entire table :

```
 //Prepare jtable plugin
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Student List',
        paging: true,
        sorting: true, // set it to false
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
        //selectOnRowClick: false, //Enable this to only select using checkboxes
```

Comment: this is correct for setting the initial sort up.  i was referring to when the user clicks on the sort headers.  can i tell that the sort column has changed so i can dis/enable the drag and drop feature?

Comment: take a look to this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155137/how-to-keep-a-single-column-from-being-reordered-in-a-jtable/1155277#1155277

Comment: looks like that is the right direction to go.  ick.